# Can we have search widget other than toolbar in android

Tags: android

i understand we can have search widget in activity toolbar. As per my requirement we can't use tool bar for search widget, Is that possible we can have search widget as a separate entity in activity just below tool bar or some any where we want (just like Text View or button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I have created the search view xml and use it by including any where i want.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:queryHint="Search..">

            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

to include in layout

```
<include layout="@layout/search_view" />
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I am trying adding voice search button also using android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton", but its not showing? Any idea about that?

Comment: i will go for it . i will notify you when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible...Do like this...

In XML

```
<FrameLayout
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/searchBoxFrame"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:background="@drawable/input_box"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:id="@+id/autoText"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:id="@+id/searchBoxCancel"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In Java

```
private EditText searchEditText;
private Button cancelButton;

searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoText);

cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBoxCancel);

private void onEditTextItemChanged() {
    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            list.clear();
            String editTextString = searchEditText.getText().toString();
            int textLength = editTextString.length();
            if (textLength > 0) {
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String searchText = "";
                searchText = list.get(i).getName().toString();
                if (textLength <= searchText.length()) {
                    // compare the String in EditText with Names in the
                    // ArrayList
                    if (searchText.toLowerCase().contains(editTextString.toLowerCase())) {
                        list.add(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            listItemsAdapter = new listItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
            listView.setAdapter(listItemsAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

}

private void onCancelButtonClicked() {
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```